# Run the cluster steps for file upload on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster with numbers of steps. I am trying to analyze log data coming in every week. I want to run the same steps every week on appended data.

**Long-running cluster**:

1. Load Log file from `data source` (load or copy records from log file if it is subsequent run)
2. Analyze data
3. Return data to the destination

How can I run the same steps every week on the cluster?

Or do I need to spin up new cluster every week?

It would be great if I could get some guidance on type of data source in such a scenario which handle huge data.

Comment: Do you wish to keep the cluster running for the rest of the week, or is your intention to turn off the cluster after doing that job each week?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Want to keep it on for custom runs/triggers.

Comment: If all you want is to ingest and analyze log data. Amazon Elasticsearch (with Logstash for ingestion, Kibana for reporting) might make more sense than EMR

Comment: i want to do etl on log data as its a custom log data that i want to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit new steps to a cluster by calling [add-steps — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html).

Thus, you would need a `cron` job somewhere that calls the cluster to add the steps. You could create the cron job on the Master node, or there are a myriad of Hadoop tools that can schedule and orchestrate jobs.

You certainly do *not* require a new node since you have a cluster already operating.

Comment: That means adding new step with same config/setup to be added to cluster. My challenge is how to handle data. I dont want data duplication. Confused on how to design data handling for cluster

Comment: The best way to use EMR is to load data directly from Amazon S3. Therefore, the data should be placed/updated in S3 before the job is triggered in EMR. If you wish to automate the transformation of data, see [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/).